# How to delay sidekiq jobs for 10 mins, and count them in the end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, sidekiq, job-scheduling

Currently I am performing specific sidekiq job every time the model attribute changed.

Example: I am changing and saving each of following attrs: title, description and text. So now 3 sidekiq jobs would be performed.

`title was changed` `description was changed` `text was changed`

How can I setup sidekiq to wait 10 mins after the first attribute change, and then perform specific job if `jobs.count > 1`?

Example: I am changing and saving each of following attrs again: title, description and text again. And now within 10 mins it should perform only 1 sidekiq job with message like.

`3 attributes were updated`

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you need some kind of debounce.
Here is a sidekiq debounce that match your criteria.

I've never tried but the readme of this gem `gem 'sidekiq-debouncer'` quite describing same kind of flows.

https://github.com/paladinsoftware/sidekiq-debouncer
Install this gem.

setup your parameter to the job that you want to consider to debounce, like primary key of the class.

So what you need is something like this.

```rb
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Debouncer

  sidekiq_options(
    debounce: {
      time: 10 * 60
    },
    by: -> (job_args) {
        job_args[0] # this is the ID you pass in the argument in `perform` method.
      }
  )

  def perform(id, attributes)
    # perform your action on that record.
    # and if you are using the class variable like I've explained below, just reset that.

  end
end
```

So that's really it.

You can use something like a class variable as I mentioned in perform method as comment that have information about those attributes that were updated but not have a sidekiq job executed for that.

```rb
class Something
  @@unperformed_updated_attributes = {}

  def setup
    @@unperformed_updated_attributes[id].merge!(updated_attribute: new_value)
  end

  def reset
    @@unperformed_updated_attributes[id] = {}
  end
end
```

This is rough presentation. but you could do something like this to achieve what you want.